# GeoCoordinateWatcher in cpp

Tags: c++, geolocation

I am writing a c++ application that should be working on Windows 7 and above.

Since it should work on Windows 7 I can't use [Windows::Devices::Geolocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR225603).

I found the [GeoCoordinateWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher.aspx) which according to MSDN is supported from windows 7+.

The problem is that I need the code to be in CPP, and it seems like this class is only a .net class.

How do I get the location using CPP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317747(v=vs.85).aspx
This has a walkthrough example in C++

Comment: Thank you. I just found this com object by querying the .net implementation.